# Setup and Deployment does not work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, setup-deployment

I am working on VS 2008 and 3.5 framework.
I had three windows services.
I placed all three in a single solution, created installer individually for each of them.
Then created a setup project.
When I build it says build failed .
But I checked on the errorlist, (i enabled the diagnostics in options menu), but there was no error at all.
I went ahead and installed. There were no issues, But there was no service showed up in the services.msc.

I installed each service individually , using installutil command, it showed up.
But my requirement is to bundle these services and deploy to the client.
The client should install it.

Where am I going wrong.
Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Regards
cmrhema

Answer (score 2):

I notice your comment above about omitting the custom action. Same mistake I made! For posterity, here's the entire process:

1. Make sure you have added the project installer to your service project ([described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28VS.80%29.aspx)). These components give your service EXE the ability to register itself with the service manager.
2. Add a setup project to your solution.
3. Add the primary output from your service project to the setup project ([described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z11b431t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)). This puts the binary into the application directory.
4. Add a custom deployment action to your setup project containing the primary output from your service project. This looks like a repeat of step 3, but what it's actually doing here is registering your service with the service manager.

[This walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) goes through each of these steps in some detail.

Answer (score 1):

I too have a similar problem with VS 2008 and I believe it is a bug in the IDE rather than anything you're doing wrong.

Basically what happens is that VS reports a failed build, but does not indicate any reason for the failure. I find that restarting Visual Studio and then performing another build allows the build to succeed.

I read somewhere that for some people the bug is caused by some auto-created project file, but a restart fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Build failed -> what else is there in the Output window?

For some general reference regarding setup projects for windows services in .net:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983650%28VS.71%29.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421

Comment: Actually I forgot to add the custom actions.

After that although the build said failed, it installed properly